# Controlling the volume while using the SndPlayAsync function on Windows Mobile 6

Tags: c#, windows-mobile-6, audio

How on earth can you control the volume of the sound played using SndPlayAsync on Windows Mobile 6??

It seems like no one knows! The documentation doesn't mention anything regarding it... 
So either there's no way, or it is kept top secret...

In addition, I am aware of the possibility of using the Windows Media Player, but I rather not, if possible.

Thanks for any help!

Aviv.

Answer (score 2):

My suggestion is:

```
[DllImport("coredll.dll", SetLastError = true)]
protected static extern int waveOutSetVolume(IntPtr device, uint volume);

[DllImport("coredll.dll", SetLastError = true)]
internal static extern int waveOutGetVolume(IntPtr device, ref int volume);
```

And then you can call methods:

```
int before;
uint maxVol = uint.MaxValue; 
waveOutGetVolume(IntPtr.Zero, ref before);
waveOutSetVolume(IntPtr.Zero, maxVol);
//Do some playing
waveOutSetVolume(IntPtr.Zero, before);
```

You can debug for other values. This will set it to highest.

Hope it helps?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `mixer...` API functions to set the master volume.  Here is a code sample:

http://www.csharp-home.com/index/tiki-read_article.php?articleId=134

To use this code in your Windows Mobile application, you need to change "winmm.dll" to "coredll.dll".  Also, these methods may not be supported in Windows Mobile, but I'm pretty sure they are.